# Devexpress Xtrareport XRlabel retrieve data from database

Tags: mysql, devexpress, xtrareport

Hello how would I retrieve data from a database and put it into xrlabel text in devexpress xtrareport? Here is my code:

```
public void getTemporaryOperatorsPermit(DataTable dt)
        {
            try
            {
                SQL = "SELECT ID FROM tbl_ID GROUP BY ID";
                cmd.Connection = dbCon;
                cmd.CommandText = SQL;
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you need to create the data dynamically as above?

Comment: yes how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches you could take, but using your method:

```
public void getTemporaryOperatorsPermit(DataTable dt)
{
    try
    {
        SQL = "SELECT ID FROM tbl_ID GROUP BY ID";
        cmd.Connection = dbCon;
        cmd.CommandText = SQL;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(reader);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet("MyDataSet");
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            var report = new XtraReport(); //breakpoint here
            report.DataSource = report;
            report.DataMember = "tbl_ID";
            report.CreateDocument();
            documentViewer.DocumentSource = report;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Above assumes you will already have a DocumentViewer instance somewhere.

Put a breakpoint where I indicated above and debug into VS then in the immediate window put:

ds.WriteXml("C:\myschema.xml", System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)

One you have the file, in the report designer just drag a label onto the form. Then select the report and in properties, find: Data Source's Schema. Set this to the file you just generated. It will populate the Field List in the designer, then all you have to do is bind the text field within the DetailReportBand to the ID field - hit its smart tag, then select your field from the DataBinding dropdown.